# How to type hint a Tuple for which the size is already known

Tags: python, tuples, sequence, type-hinting, mypy

I am learning to incorporate type hinting into my code and came across the following problem. Suppose I have `temp.py` as below:

```
from typing import List

def deal(size: int, items: List[str]):
  return tuple(items[i] for i in range(size))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(deal(3, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']))
```

The returned value from function `deal` is of `Tuple` type. Moreover I know this tuple will always have length of size.

How would I add an annotation for the return type which ensures `Type` is always of length `size`?

Comment: You don't, since `size` is a variable.

Comment: You can't, really, you'd have to type it as `Tuple[str, ...]` (or make the type the list and tuple contain generic). You can see from https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple there's no way to dynamically specify a size.

Comment: you can, however, provide in the docstring that the iterable should be of length `size`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I also see based on this PEP (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) that importing collections from `typing` is depreated. Should I be using `tuple` instead?

Comment: If you're using a new enough version of Python, yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. I'm using 3.10. Thanks.

Comment: You could add a lot of `@overload`s together with `Literal`. E.g. `Literal[1] -> Tuple[str]`, `Literal[2] -> Tuple[str, str]`. But i don't think that's worth it.